# Glass spherical lamp - How to create correct light diffusion inside the glass

Tags: glass

I am trying to render a suspended lamp made of spherical glass with led source inside. Here is my reference image:[image: Refernce image]

I have modeled a very simple object made by 3 elements:
- Light source: An hemisphere with emission material, like is in real world (see this diffuser for led: http://download.khatod.com/documents/pljt20_test_report.pdf). Light orange in the image.
- A painted metal tube for suspension (dark orange in the image)
- A glass sphere diameter 7.5cm with hole inside, like is in real world (black in the image). The glass is 3cm thick.

[image: objects]

And this is my result (5000 sample), quite disappointing. 
[image]
I tried many variants with Light Path in the glass material, different glasses roughness... without results.

[image: Glass Material]
[image: rendersettings]

How can I improve? I would like my glass sphere will be "real".
Many thanks!

**Blend file:**

[image]

Comment: Could you upload blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? It's hard to tell without some experiments.

Comment: Hi, here is the blend: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5071" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5071/) The HDRI is missing for file weight reasons. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this lamp should be built but I think the solution for your problem would be to add thickness to the glass part - separate it from the rest and add solidify modifier with 1-2mm. Also try to use only glass shader for it.